# Firestore Database Rules: Permissions for Queries

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query documents based on a field.

Because of this field I do have permissions to read this document:

```
match /lists/{list=**} {
    allow read: if resource.data.name == 'MyDocument'
}
```

If I'm trying to retrieve this document directly it's successful (Android client using Kotlin):

```
val doc = db.document("lists/acaa0247-eccd-4ff0-b986-7f8b6187e45f")
doc.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // here it works
                println("This Works")
            } else {
                println("Failed")
            }
        }
```

But when I'm querying for it (or just trying to get all documents in the collection), I get a permission denied exception:

```
val collection = db.collection("lists")
collection.get().addOnCompleteListener(activity, { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                println("Should work")
            } else {
                // Here is isn't working
                println("Failed")
            }
        })
```

This query works when I allow everyone to read all the documents under `/lists`:

```
match /lists/{list=**} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null
}
```

So my question is: Does the user need read access on all documents which are searched in the query?
In my case this would mean all documents with all fields in `/lists`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is: Does the user need read access on all documents which are searched in the query?

Yes.

To avoid getting the error when you query the list, on the client you can use the where clause to only read documents you have permissions to read.

Comment: So when using `collection.whereEqualTo("name", "MyDocument").get()` it should work? Just tried it and I also get an permission denied exception.

Comment: Yes excatly. Then you will create an index, and in the security rules make sure the user actually have access.

Comment: Btw @MarcelBochtler - look up the query syntax here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Is my query syntax incorrect? Because with the rule `allow read: if resource.data.name == "MyDocument"` and the query `collection.whereEqualTo("name", "MyDocument").get()` it is not working. The name is a field in a document in `/lists/{listId}`

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, I think you are looking at the wrong documentation? The syntax should be like this: `citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");`

Comment: I'm using Kotlin on Android. I'm gonna add this to the question. So my query should be correct.

Comment: ok - makes sense. And what security rule do you have on lists?

Comment: Found the problem: I acutally wasn't using "MyDocument" as name, but "Zähler". Changed it, because it was german. When I remove the umlaut the query with the where clause is working.

Comment: @MarcelBochtler would you accept the answer if it solved your issue?

Comment: Important to note: You MUST use `read` instead of `get` in your rules. This didn't seem to work for me, but when I changed my rules to `read`, it worked.